# Upgrade SQL Server 2012 to 2014 or 2016 for Sharepoint Server 2016 instance

Tags: 2016, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with Sharepoint Server 2016 installed but the SQL server version is 2012. What do I need to do to upgrade the database to 2014 or 2016. Everything is installed in the same machine Sharepoint + Database. What I need to check to performf this upgrade and if you have any guide I can follow it would be really appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: did you install sharepoint 2016 with SQL 2012?

Comment: Yes but I want to upgrade SQL Server to a newer version

Comment: SharePoint is not supported with Sql Server 2012? do u have any data in your farm?

Comment: Yes, Can I run the SQL Server 2014 installer to update it?

Answer (score 0):

As you current configuration is not on supported software, i would do in the following way.

- Take the backup of current content Databases
- Rebuild new SharePoint 2016 Farm with desired SQL version (SQL 2016)
- create and configure Service Application & web application
- restore the database from backup and upgrade on SQL server then attach to SharePoint.
- Now test the application.